# What happens if you design the logo of your website in "jpg" format instead of "png"?

Tags: image, web, format, png, jpeg

I'm already aware of this fact that we should avoid "jpg/jpeg" image format for logo. But I'd like to know what the result would be if we use jpg. Thanks.

Comment: Care to site any sources for such assertion?

Comment: http://www.soliddocuments.com/screen_capture/_png_file_format/78/2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The big problems with saving drawings in JPEG is that you will get blurring between color transitions.

Comment: Yes I totally agree with you. PNG has many advantages over jpg, but...you know...? I feel like the quality of my logo decreases when I save it as png... I don't know if it's due to my optical illusion or real... (the size of logo is 62px in 62px). Have any idea?

Comment: @TumajNuri: PNG compression is **lossless**. Unless you do something else to your image as well (up or downscaling, resampling), you get to see the exact same image as when you originally designed it.

Comment: Still you are right. It looks low-quality because I made it smaller, which happens to all images in any format we re-size them. The outline/edges of my logo looks so jaggered when I make it smaller. But as you said, png usually operates without "loss". Unfortunately I couldn't find any solution for that. Looks like any website with small (iconic) logo has the same problem. It doesn't matter which format I save my logo as. Almost any picture smaller than 200px looks terrible.

Answer (score 0):

"Nothing" will happen if you use a jpeg image, but jpeg is more for photographs and when you have shadings of light and dark, in particular you lose transparency and fading effects which might be important for stellar logo designs.

But it's not the end of your future if you use jpeg, but PNG is preferred.

Comment: Oh good answer! those shading and effects in tiff/psd/png format that we lose when save/export as "jpeg". right?

Comment: You are right but I feel like my logo loses quality when i save it as jpeg.

Comment: Well, PNG is also uses lossless compression - so when you save it as PNG, and the size is compressed, you don't lose data, but as JPEG, you can only shrink the size up to 5 times without losing data, then you start to lose some. So if you're original picture is not of a high enough quality - I think that's what happens.